# How to bind from a listItem template to a property in the list itself?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, relativesource

I have a class (class A) that contains a list (list A)  and and integer (int A).
I also have a listview that its itemssource is bound to "list A".
The listitems have a template that shows the itmes content (bound to its properties).
I also want the template to use "int A" and show it.

how can I bind something inside the template (which its datacontext is listItem), to the class that contains the list (or even to the list itself) ?

thanks,
Yos.

Answer (score 1):

Usually that should be possible with a relative source binding that targets a control which still has the DataContext containing the property:

```xml
{Binding DataContext.ThatIntProperty,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the List/Items do not have a reference to `class A` thats not possible, becuase the list could be refenrenced somewhere else too.
You can add something like a `classA Owner {get;set;}` property to your objects in the list and set this to `class A` whenever a item is added to the list (the `CollectionChanged`-event can handle that if you use an `ObservableCollection`).

Comment: Ok, thanks... so I can't bind to class A but can I bind to the list A?

Comment: And in the same subject: if I have a grid which has 2 columns... in the I put a text ox in the first column: <textbox grid.column=0 />
can I bind the textbox to the column that contains it? (lets sat print the width of the column inside the textbox)

Comment: In theory you can bind to nearly everything, but you can not access a `Parent`-Object without having a reference to it...

Comment: See H.B.'s answer how to bind to ancestors - that works because all UIElements have such a "Parent-reference" by default.

Comment: Maybe I wasent clear enough: 
<Grid> 
<Grid.ColumnDefinition /> 
<Grid.ColumnDefinition /> 
<Textbox grid.column=0 text=......./> 
<Grid />

can I bind the text to the column width? (it is not his parent in the tree)

Comment: As long as they have a common parent element you can go up to that and then down from that, but to understand your question better may add it to your initial question with "readable formatting"...